# How to rerun only Failed Jobs on Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline that configures a device.
This pipeline is to be run on multiple VMs which are done through Environment resource tagging.

So I have Environment A, which has around 10 VMs/resources, and I will run the pipeline on these 10Vms.

Now, the job will fail on some of these VMs, now the issue is that when I click on Rerun Failed Jobs, it is running on all the VMs again, not just the failed ones.

Is there any way I can fix this?

[image: Rerun Failed Job button]

[image: Only the last 2 should run]

Comment: This is an issue that needs to be addressed where it should only rerun failed jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It is a known limitation. Review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-strategy-rolling?view=azure-pipelines#remarks).

> There are a few known gaps in this feature. For example, when you retry a stage, it will re-run the deployment on all VMs not just failed targets.